# Analyzing frequency of characters in a line of text

Tags: java, arrays, frequency

How do I create a code that analyzes the frequency of characters in a line of text in Java?

I know I have to use an array, but I don't fully understand arrays and I'm not quite sure how to go about this. I need to include every letter (only uppercase), digits, spaces, and 6 punctuation marks (`"-'.!,`).

So if the user inputs a line that reads: `A-C E'? 099A "`

The output should look like this:

```
A:2
C:1
E:1
DIGITS:3
SPACES:3
PUNCTUATION:3
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Split the input `String` into a `char[]` and iterate over that array using a `for` loop. Create counters to count. For each character, run checks against it.

I gave a pretty good answer on that subject to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35548009/count-and-display-uppercase-lowercase-and-numbers/35548218#35548218).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). HashMaps contain pairs of keys and values. Thus, you can iterate the string adding new values (with count 1) or increment values already existing with a simple if statement.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    char c = string.charAt(i);
    String s = String.valueOf(c);
    if (hm.containsKey(s)) {
        int count = hm.get(s);
        hm.put(s, count + 1);
    } else {
        hm.put(s, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another method if hashmaps sound too complicated

```
public static void CharSearcher() {
    int Counter;
    String inputString = "A-C E'? 099A";
    char[] charArray = inputString.toCharArray();

    for (Counter = 0; Counter < charArray.length; Counter++)
    {
        int num = 0;
        char current = charArray[Counter];

        for (int innerCounter = 0; innerCounter < charArray.length;
                innerCounter++)
        {
            if (charArray[innerCounter] == current) {
                num++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(current + ":" + num);
    }
}
```

This will list all your Characters with the amount of times they appear, now all you have to do is adjust the code to display them how you want.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful because we haven't learned about hashmaps yet in my class! How do I go about counting both upper and lower case letters as the same, so it all shows up as upper case in the output?

Comment: In order to count upper and lower case letters as both the same you need to convert your String either to all lower case by doing this: `inputString.toLowerCase();` or all Upper case by doing this: `inputString.toUpperCase();`